# What evidence can be the unambiguous proof of Majorana fermions in condensed matter?

Tags: condensed-matter

Although in recent years many papers claimed that they observed Majorana fermions in condensed matter, most of them are questioned because of the inability to rule out alternative explanations. So is there a “gold standard” of the evidence of Majorana fermions in condensed matter?